# When generating contract metadata with `sp.init_metadata` do you include or exclude on-chain views in the `views` array in the metadata?

Tags: blockchain, metadata, smartcontracts

When I perform `self.init_metadata("metadata", some_metadata)` on contract metadata inside [SmartPy](https://smartpy.io/), should the list of views inside the TZIP-16 (https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-16/) metadata only contain off-chain views, or must on-chain views also be included in this information?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the compiler interprets on-chain views the same way as off-chain views when it comes to metadata (not included in the contract code).

If the off-chain view has the same logic as the on-chain view, you can remove the off-chain entirely and just use the on-chain view.